# Issue with rand() function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random, fetch

I'm having a little trouble with my rand() function. I have the following query:

```
$listTrainers = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT emp_id FROM employees;"); 

    while($fetchTrainers = mysqli_fetch_row($listTrainers))
    {
        echo 'ID: ' . $fetchTrainers['0']. '<br>';

    }
```

This query returns me the id of all employees in the database, is there a way I can randomly select one of these id's and store it in a variable?

I am trying to use the following function:

```
echo(rand(begin, end));
```

where begin is the first element from the query and end is the last element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your query:

```
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed, and simple too. Thanks for the help, i'll accept your answer when I can

Answer (score 2):

You can do so within your query easily

```
SELECT emp_id FROM employees ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do this directly in the database, to avoid getting all IDs if you only need one:

```
SELECT
    emp_id
FROM
    employees
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT
    1
```

If you do need all IDs, but additionally want to pick a random one, use this to avoid querying the database twice:

```
$listTrainers = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT emp_id FROM employees;"); 

while($fetchTrainers = mysqli_fetch_row($listTrainers))
{
    $id = $fetchTrainers[0];
    echo 'ID: ' . $id . '<br>';
    $ids[] = $id;
}
$randomId = $ids[array_rand($ids)];
```